# Why does Linked Table Manager refer to deleted table?

Tags: ms-access

I recently split my database with BE being stored on the network drive. When I open the DB and run Linked Table Manager to refresh linked tables, I get an error message that one of the tables has incorrect or long name. Looking at the table name, it refers to one of the tables that I have deleted long time ago (before db has been split and tables linked) and never used it but for some reason Linked Table Manager still sees it somewhere.

I repeat that this table does not exist anymore in my DB as it has been deleted. Do you know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Try to run a Compact & Repair on your frontend db.

Comment: Did that a couple of times but the error message still shows. Here is the image: https://hmp.me/cmbo

Comment: When does this message popup? If nothing else fixes, import everything to a new db.

Comment: It happens when I select all tables in Linked Table Manager and click OK button (to refresh linked tables).

Comment: Actually it only happens when I try to refresh specific table which used to have a relationship with the deleted table that Linked Table Manager constantly refers to. I am not sure why it still tries to locate it since it was deleted soon after it was created.

Comment: Please read [ask] then add the additional infos from your comments to the question (edit), like the relationship (what likely caused the trouble) and the error-msg (but as text not image!)